# How to transport a knife that falls under the Weapons Act

Tags: germany, weapons

In Germany, there is a law ([Weapons Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/waffg_2002/__42a.html)) that prohibits the carrying of a knife with a blade length of 12 cm. "Fixed knives with a blade length of more than 12 centimetres, any knives classified as cutting and thrusting weapons and folding knives that can be unfolded with one hand may not be carried in public."

Now I wonder what it's like to buy such a knife in a shop and take it home. Is that already prohibited?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Weapons Act and quote the relevant extracts, please.

Comment: @Rick https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/waffg_2002/__42a.html

Comment: The key part here is "carrying", if it's in its original packaging, and it's blade or handle is contained, then you're transporting, rather than carrying.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Obviously, there are plenty of kitchen knives over 12 cm in length.

A knife that is legal for home use be carried outside the home in an enclosed compartment (*verschlossenes Behältnis*) which prevents immediate access. So it is forbidden to carry the knife thrust through a belt, or in a jacket pocket, but it can carried in a [locked tool box](https://www.berlin.de/polizei/service/waffenbehoerde/waffenrecht-uebersicht/#f%C3%BChrungsverbot) or the like. A shrink-wrapped package also qualifies.

To carry it "unwrapped" is forbidden, but there are exceptions to that ban which come down to "reasonable use." A bread knife would be reasonable if it comes with a loaf of bread and all the other implements for a picnic. It is not reasonable in a nightclub.

A number of knife styles or cutting implements are generally [forbidden](https://www.berlin.de/polizei/service/waffenbehoerde/waffenrecht-uebersicht/artikel.1044011.php), no matter how they are carried or stored.

Comment: How old is this law? As a tourist in Berlin 20+ years ago I bought a spring loaded knife in a hardware store for no logical reason. Would the same law have been in effect then? Note that I later found it would be allowed into the US if I only had one usable hand. With two hands I surrendered it.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, the law gets revised every now and then. I can't tell you what the rules were two decades ago. Three decades ago, laws in West Berlin were even more convoluted.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite The law is revised from time to time, and there were some substantial changes around 2007-ish which had some media attention because the change actually affected some things in everyday use at the time. So what was ok 20+ years ago might not be anymore. Especially spring-loaded knives and things like butterfly knives had restrictions added in the 2000s and early 2010s.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Spring loaded knives like Stilettos are illegal since the early 2000s together with Balisongs or any item that mimics it.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite The current version of the law (the knife must be transported in a locked box) exists since April 2008; spring loaded knifes that can be opened with only one hand are forbiden since April 2003.

Comment: Does this mean when I want to take my kitchen knives to get them sharpened somewhere I need to put them in a locked compartment for transport? The last time I've just wrapped it in a towel and put it in my backpack :/

Comment: Gotcha, always carry an extra loaf of bread on your way back from the picnic.

Comment: I'm now having visions of getting mugged by a guy wielding a knife and a loaf.

Comment: @Tim, there are two ways to carry that knife, in a locked container or in a reasonable manner. If you fear that your definition of 'reasonable' does not meet court approval, take the container.

Comment: Wait, so i can't make myself a sandwich in a nightclub just because i don't like pre-sliced bread? that's discrimination /s

Comment: Does being dressed as a knight while on your way to (or home from) a medieval re-enactment count as "reasonable" for carrying knives (and swords, axes, and similar bladed weapons that may-or-may-not be legally classed as knives) in Germany?

Comment: @nick012000, no idea, but it might matter how sharp they are. Much more reasonable to get a bag with a padlock. (If you see a guy with a padlocked guitar case, there is even money that he is a sports shooter and not carrying an expensive guitar ...) There are some exceptions for traditional display, but that does not usually mean modern-style reenactors.

Answer (score 15):

According to [section 42a](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/waffg_2002/__42a.html) Weapons Act (WaffG), Paragraph 1forbids:

> - 3. Knives with a blade that can be locked with one hand (one-hand knife) or fixed knives with a blade length of more than 12 cm respectively.

But, at Paragraph 2, there are two potentially relevant statutory defences to carrying such a knife home from the shop:

> (2) Paragraph 1 does not apply:
>
> - 2. for transport in a closed container,
> - 3. for carrying the objects according to paragraph 1 nos. 2 and 3, provided that there is **a legitimate interest**.

And Paragraph 3 defines *legitimate interest* to mean:

> (3) A legitimate interest pursuant to paragraph 2(3) exists in particular if the items are carried in connection with the exercise of a profession, the maintenance of customs, sport or **a generally recognized purpose**.

If, as user @o.m. pointed out in their comment, the knife remains in its original packaging - i.e. within a "*closed container*" - then Paragraph 2(2) would presumably apply.

If not, I strongly suspect that taking it home directly after buying it would be "*a generally recognized purpose*" so not prohibited under this Act.

<sub>(The above quotations are via Google Translate, and I've altered them slightly to make sense in English)</sub>

Comment: Transport home would usually be deemed a closed container, if one doesn't open the sales packaging.

Comment: @o.m. depends on the sale point - if you buy a blade after testing it (common with high-quality knives!) there is no seal on the container, but it is only a cardboard box, which is not considered closed. Though, you may have a legitimate interest and recognized purpose such as hunting or carrying your tools of the trade (e.g. hunters, butchers, cooks on the way to using said tools)

Comment: The UK seems to have very similar regulations. The advice I was given for buying them was:
1) Keep the receipt, and if you've opened the box get the shop to retape it
2) Don't linger an overly long time with it in your possession before taking it home or locking it in your car - some more shopping is almost certainly fine, a long dinner probably not.
3) Bringing in knives to be sharpened - it's probably a good idea to make an appointment for this.
being able to show legitimate reasons to carry a knife, and that you're taking due care, is sensible even if you're sure of your legal rights

Comment: @lupe How does locking in a car help? The German police can look for knives that are not in a closed container in a car and you will be in the same trouble as if you had it on you outside of the car. They especially like to check cars with registration signs from certain countries with more liberal knife laws. Many personal stories available on the web.